# i uploaded my site to hostinger but i encountered the following problems

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.12'
>   (using password: NO) in
>   /home/u749031689/public_html/Enrollment/includes/dbcon.php on line 8
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.12' (using password: NO)Not

```
<?php
$Server="localhost";
$unameDB ="root";
$passDB  ="";
$dbName="u749031689_enrol";
$sqlCon = mysql_connect($Server, $unameDB, $passDB) or die (mysql_error(). "Not connected");
mysql_select_db($dbName, $sqlCon);
?>
```

Comment: Please check your _phpmyadmin_ (i.e. MySql) username and password.

Comment: Hello, you are using function mysql_connect which is deprecated in php 5.x versions and totally removed from php 7 version. Please check on what php version is your host running and in any case be advised to use MySQLi or PDO for all data base connection / queries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your database to the hostinger server and then you need to replace your '$Server', '$unameDB', '$passDB' and '$dbName' values as per your hostinger database details.

Your code would be as follows.

```
<?php
$Server="YOUR HOSTINGERS DATABASE SERVER NAME";
$unameDB ="YOUR HOSTINGERS DATABASE USER NAME";
$passDB  ="YOUR HOSTINGERS DATABASE PASSWORD";
$dbName="u749031689_enrol";
$sqlCon = mysql_connect($Server, $unameDB, $passDB) or die (mysql_error(). "Not connected");
mysql_select_db($sqlCon, $dbName);
?>
```

Comment: mySQL Database =u749031689
mySQL user = u749031689_root
mySQL host = mysql.hostinger.ph

Comment: Yes you are right, your database on hostinger is "u749031689_enrol", but you also have to check your server host name, mysql username and password. To check this go to the hostinger cpanel and then click on the mysql/phpmyadmin there you can find your username and password for database connection

Comment: and then what will i change in the connection?

Comment: @deadpirate: You require to setup that correct variables for mySql connection.